# Program to print out basic details by user. Keep getting errors in output

Tags: c

so I'm trying to create a program that allows a user to enter there name, DOB, and phone number then lists it all together as a printf statement. I noticed every time i run the program it doesn't print my name rather that it replaces it with my birth month and the phone number pops out as random gibberish. Any idea what i did wrong?? Thank you in advance.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    
      char name[26];
     int day, year,cellPhone;
     
    scanf("%s", name);
    scanf("%s %d %d", name, &day, &year);
    scanf("%d", &cellPhone);
      
       printf("Name:%s\n", name);
    printf("DOB:%s %d %d\n", name,day,year);
    printf("Mobile:%d",cellPhone );
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", name);
scanf("%s %d %d", name,` - why are you reading the name twice?

Comment: `int` is not an appropriate data type to store phone numbers. Phone numbers are essentially character sequences, not real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but they are easy fixes.

Firstly, you should probably have `printf` statements before each `scanf` so the user knows what to input.

Second, why are you using name twice? You need to declare another variable for the name of the month. This is why its printing your name as the birth month. Whether you choose a string or number format is your choice.

Finally, the reason you are getting gibberish with the phone number is most likely because the number you are inputting is too large for a double. You can used some sort of unsigned int or just use a string, which is probably better for input in this case.

Here is my suggestion for your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char name[32];
    char cellPhone[32];
    char month[32];
    int day, year;

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Please enter your DOB (Month ## ####): ");
    scanf("%s %d %d", month, &day, &year);
    printf("Please enter your cell number: ");
    scanf("%s", cellPhone);
  
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("DOB: %s %d %d\n", month,day,year);
    printf("Mobile: %s",cellPhone );

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions for your code:

1. You should user `char[]` to store phone numbers.
2. Use `fgets()` to input string rather than `scanf`. If you wnt to use scanf then use it like this: `scanf("%26s", name)`
3. In second scanf statement for DOB input your're doing `scanf("%s %d %d", name, &day, &year)`. Maybe you're missing month element of DOB? You've already taken name as input so it's going to override old value

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```c
char name[26], cellPhone[10];
int day, month, year;

fgets(name, 26, stdin);
fgets(cellPhone, 10, stdin);
scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);

printf("%s", name);
printf("DOB:%d %d %d\n",day, month, year);
printf("Mobile:%s",cellPhone);
```

When I run it, I seem to get desired output:

```
[rohaan@localhost c-posts]$ ./a.out 
Rohan Kumar
+92334312
23 10 1994
Rohan Kumar
DOB:23 10 1994
Mobile:+92334312
```